# Decision Tree Giving Impossible Splits

Tags: spss, cart

I ran a decision tree in SPSS, using the CHAID method. The result was a tree with many nodes. Some of the splits were impossible. For example: for a variable that is from 0 to 10 (in %), a split was >100 vs. <=100. Another example: a non-negative variable had a negative split.

Does anyone have an idea how this is possible ?

Comment: Can you confirm (histogram plot) that your values are what you think they are?  Can you tell something about inputs, and settings?

Comment: Sounds like a scale problem.  Try mean-zero standardizing the variable values first.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this is possible: it would result in groups with no cases.  You might want to look especially at missing value definitions - perhaps some missing values are negative but are not declared.